# Is there a way to covert date (with different format) into a standardized format in python?

Tags: python, pandas, date, python-re

I have a column calls "date" which is an object and it has very different date format like dd.m.yy, dd.mm.yyyy, dd/mm/yyyy, dd/mm, m/d/yyyy etc as below. Obviously by simply using df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) will not work. I wonder for messy date value like that, is there anyway to standardized and covert the date into one single format ?

```
date
17.2.22 # means Feb 17 2022
23.02.22 # means Feb 23 2022
17/02/2022 # means Feb 17 2022
18.2.22 # means Feb 18 2022
2/22/2022 # means Feb 22 2022
3/1/2022 # means March 1 2022
<more messy different format>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coerce the dates to datetime and allow invalid entries to be turned into nulls.Also, allow pandas to infer the format. code below

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce',infer_datetime_format=True)


    date
0 2022-02-17
1 2022-02-23
2 2022-02-17
3 2022-02-18
4 2022-02-22
5 2022-03-01
```

Comment: Thanks wwnde, this works great. One issue, I have date shown as 8/3/2022 but it really means March 8, 2022. In this case, is there a way to read it correctly? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You may have to forego one or the other. Forinstance, wehereas the following will get it doe, it will alter the last date in your sample `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=False, errors='coerce',infer_datetime_format=True)`

Comment: Thanks wwnde. I realized in my real dataset, the date format are much more messy than what I show here. I am unable to normalized them all.  But your advice is really great and I appreciated your helps.

Answer (score 0):

Based on wwnde's solution, the following works in my real dataset -

```
df['date'].fillna('',inplace=True)
df['date'] = df['date'].astype('str')
df['date new'] = df['date'].str.replace('.','/')
df['date new'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date new'],
errors='coerce',infer_datetime_format=True)
```